# Resize an image with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, image-processing, avfoundation, opengl-es-2.0

My problem is simple: I have to process each frame of a video. The process computes a zone to crop on the original frame. To have better performances, I have to downscale the original frame. Nowadays, It is done thanks to a dedicated library. However, it is slow. We are wondering if there is any possibility to downscale this frame thanks to OpenGL ES 2.0 glsl.

David

Comment: are you trying to downsize them in realtime? Or is there some possibility of you doing a preprocess stage before presenting the video

Comment: In fact my processsing should occur in real time during video playback. I will check wwdc 2012 video.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AV Foundation to load the video from disk or to pull video from the camera, you could use my open source [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework to handle the underlying OpenGL ES processing for you.

Specifically, you can use a GPUImageCropFilter to crop out a selected region of the input video using normalized 0.0-1.0 coordinates in a CGRect. The FilterShowcase example shows how this works in practice for live video from the camera. With this, you don't need to touch any manual OpenGL ES API calls if you don't want to.

Comment: Thanks Brad I already follows your project in github :). I will use your crop filter at the end of my video pipeline. Before cropping each frame, i need to compute à bounding box. And to process it i need to have a subsampled frame (from HD i need a 320x200 image).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i Will use a frame buffer object to render my texture. I will set the viewport to desired size and render my texture as usual. To get back downsampled image, i Will use glGetReadPixels.

David